# Write Python function to create MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql

I’m trying to write a function to create a database table and check if table exist but I am getting the following error. Here is my code and corresponding error:

```
def create_table1(name, *args):
    table_name = mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE {name} ({args} VARCHAR(255))")
    mycursor.execute(table_name)
    print(f"{name} table is created successfully!")
    return True
```

Error:

```
File "db.py", line 22
    table_name = mycursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE {name} ({args} VARCHAR(255))")
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there anyone can help?
Thanks,

Comment: `args` is a tuple, here needs a `str`

Comment: The function argument *args is unpacked as tuple and your SQL is invalid then.
CREATE TABLE tere (('some_argument',) VARCHAR(255)). And it cannot be argument with * because you cannot unpack it like this anyway, it would create CREATE TABLE tere (('some_argument', 'some_argument2',...) VARCHAR(255)) and this is not valid SQL. So you should change the *args to just field_name or something.

Comment: Best bet for debugging is to stick that sql that is being generated into a variable and print it out to see what your resulting sql looks like. Likely it's malformed as @qristjan noted.

Comment: Not sure. But on a `SyntaxError` we assume that we have a syntax error in our code. But other functions, objects can raise this exception too (like `PyMySQL` etc). And as @qristjan mentioned you definitely have a syntax error in the SQL Query.

Comment: This is a Python SyntaxError, the SQL hasn't been parsed yet.  Most likely there is something wrong in the code that we can't see.